# TabBar combined with Navigation Bar / Search Bar and TableView

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisearchbar

I used a TabBar in my iPhone application and integrated it programmatically.
I have several TabBarItems in it and every click will load a XYZ-ViewController with a corresponding XYZ-View.xib.

Now I use to have a screen with the TabBar and a NavBar with SearchBar and a segmented control like in this example of Apple:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableSearch/index.html

But in this example, there is not a TabBar and copy the source into my project causes the problem, that I did the loading in XViewController.m viewDidLoad method:

```
// Add create and configure the navigation controller.
MyAppDelegate *myAppDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

// Add create and configure the navigation controller.
UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationControlleralloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
myAppDelegate.navController = navigationController;
[navigationController release];
[myAppDelegate.window addSubview:myAppDelegate.navController.view];
```

The effect is, that there is a toolbar with the correct title, but there is no searchbar and no TabBar at the bottom.

Could anyone give me a hint what's wrong here?

Comment: The searchbar is there. I have to reconnect the Outlets and then all is okay with the search.

But the main problem still exists: The TabBar disappears behind the TableView. The TableView seems to overlay it. Clicking a tableviewcell, it flips to the next screen with the right toolbar and a "back button" and here I see the TabBar, but it is not clickable.

So, what's wrong here? What I have to do?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:test2ViewController];

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:test1ViewController, navigationController, test3ViewController, nil];
[self.myTabBarController setViewControllers:controllers];
```